# Reload Freeradius clients without restart the service

Tags: configuration, freeradius, freeradius2, ubuntu-12.04

Is there a way to reload the Freeradius clients configuration without restarting the service? I'm using:

```
Ubuntu Server 12
Freeradius 2.1.10
MySQL v5.5.20 (I'm storing the clients in the "nas" table)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending a SIGHUP to the process will reload the configuration.

The Ubuntu init script seems to take care of this for you - try `service freeradius reload`.

Comment: Neither of these worked for me on Upuntu 10.04 LTS. Caused me no end of confusion before I realized I had to restart the Rasius server to get the new Client to register. It reloaded a lot of other configs tho. Looking in the logs at /var/log/freeradius helped.

Comment: It is not working. I am getting this in the log: `HUP - No files changed.  Ignoring`

Comment: @LatinSuD If you `touch /etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf` before sending the HUP, it should work (free radius does not check all config files for changes).